# NSDate compare is false?

Tags: objective-c

i compare 2 NSDates which are the same and i get false result.
i cant show how i get this dates because its too long , but i can show what i do :

```
NSLog(@"this date is:%@ , and date we check to equality is:%@",thisDate,dateToFind);
if([thisDate isEqualToDate:dateToFind]  )
{
    NSLog(@"equal date!"); // not printed! 
}
```

the NSLog show me this :

```
this date is:2012-09-13 14:23:54 +0000 , and date we check to equality is:2012-09-13 14:23:54 +0000
```

he doesnt print the NSLog . 
why ?

Comment: Do you get a different result if you try `[thisDate compare:dateToFind] == NSOrderedSame`? Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713638/nsdate-isequaltodate-not-working-does-it-look-at-seconds-and-split-seconds - perhaps the dates differ in microseconds ...

Comment: same result. and its happen only for the dates of today , the dates of yesterday are ok. it cant be ms delta , cause its the same date from array which i just reordered so , i am looking after a date which i already have .

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176303/comparing-two-nsdate-objects-not-working

Answer (score 1):

As a few have said it seems to be the fractions of a second that are giving you trouble. The reason for this is that an `NSDate` is simply an object wrapper around an `NSTimeInterval`(`double`) with a value in seconds since the reference date(12AM January 1 2001 GMT).

There are a couple main ways to deal with this. Either check the date to see if it is in a given range, or (more likely based on your question) truncate the fractions of a second completely off.

Truncating seconds from an `NSDate` is trivial code. You may want to truncate all of the dates that you are storing as you store them for quick comparisons. You can truncate an existing `NSDate` like this:

```
NSDate *truncatedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:((NSTimeInterval)lround(originalDateObject.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))];
```

This code is pretty self explanatory. It grabs the date's backing time interval rounds it to an integer casts that back to a time interval and creates a new truncated date.

Once you do this to both dates you can then compare your two truncated dates and they will behave as expected.

Or if you must do something without changing your date data you could simply do:

```
if (lround(thisDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) == lround(dateToFind.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)){
    // If whole seconds are equal, as shown in log, this will execute.
}
```

Comment: It is the fractions of a second.  Internally dates are stored as double precision floating point numbers.  Comparing two NDates for equality is exactly the same problem as comparing two floating point numbers.

Comment: @JeremyP I guess we're on the same page. I just saw your comment after finishing an edit to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"this date is:%@ , and date we check to equality is:%@",
      thisDate,dateToFind);
```

Try changing the above with:

```
NSLog(@"this date is:%f , and date we check to equality is:%f",
      [thisDate timeIntervalSince1970],
      [dateToFind timeIntervalSince1970]);
```